# Repeatedly check the login status of the user?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to regularly check the status of the logged in user. My method is as follows but I am unsure as to whether this is the best way to go about it.

```
window.fbAsyncInit=function(){
    FB.init({
        appId:'123',
        status:true,
        cookie:true,
        xfbml:true,
        channelUrl:'file',
        oauth:true
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(a){
            // do something
        },300000);
    });
}
```

**I am aware of the 'subscribe' functions but I am not really sure what they are for. If these are suitable then I will consider using them but I need to have a clearer picture of what they do and how often. I have read the documentation and they simply say that it attaches a handler. This is not very detailed!! What does it attach a handler to!!??**

Additionally, if I want to call FB.getLoginStatus outside of the 'fbAsyncInit' function, is this possible?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a long time on this issue, I decided to go with my `setTimeout` solution. This was for several reasons:

1. The event.subscribe did not work very well at all, in fact, it might as well be rendered useless!! I managed to get it to fire but the event was only firing after approximately half an hour of logging out of Facebook. In addition, it detaches itself if no session is found and therefore it does not detect if you login to Facebook.
2. With my method I know exactly when the event will fire and I have a lot more control over it.

So now, if you have Facebook open in another tab and login or log out, my site will detect this and change the content on the page accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a good look at the FB.subscribe functions, it's purpose is exactly what you are looking for.  Polling for any event is generally bad design and can get pretty messy on more complex implementations.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  // do something with response
});
```

The above 'subscribes' you to 'auth.login' event.  Meaning, everytime the 'auth.login' status changes, the above callback is run.  you can replace the event with several other supported events, and run call-backs as and when they arrive.  If you want to dynamically stop listening to the any event, you can at anytime in your code invoke event.unsubscribe, and voila, you are no longer listening for event changes.

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: That is what I thought but I have tested this and it does not work in this way. I set up an alert on the event and when I logged in and out of Facebook in a different tab, nothing happened. The alert only went off when I loaded the page.